# Adding Dynamic link with Spaces in variable

Tags: php, html, dynamic, hyperlink

i am trying to create a dynamic link. $path="uploads/" and $fileName="Data Communication and Networking.pdf" which is retrieved from database. But the link gets created with href="upload/Data" ignoring the " Communication and Networking.pdf" part. How to add $fileName with spaces between the content.

```
$message=$row["message"];       
$fileName=$row["filename"];
$date=$row["date"];   

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$Serial."</td>";
echo "<td>".$message."</td>";

echo "<td><a href=".$path.$fileName.">Download</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$Serial++;;
```

Comment: you can try using urlencode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` value must consist in quotes. Place single quotes around your value.change your `href` as below:

```
echo "<td><a href='".$path.$fileName."'>Download</a></td>";
```

Comment: glad to help @CoolCompiler

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any space with `%20`

```
$CompletePath = str_replace(" ", "%20", $path . $fileName);
echo "<td><a href=" . $CompletePath . ">Download</a></td>";
//uploads/Data%20Communication%20and%20Networking.pdf is a valid URL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path="/path";
$filename="/file with space.name";
echo "<td><a href=".$path.$fileName.">Download</a></td>";
```

Will output:

```
`<td><a href=/path/file with space.name>Download</a></td>`
```

So you need to put the path between the quotes like this:

```
$path="/path";
$filename="/file with space.name";
echo "<td><a href='".$path.$fileName."'>Download</a></td>";
```